# Получить id строки с использованием jquery context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

В приложении на asp.net mvc использую билиотеку jquery context menu.
Вот мой код:

```
$.contextMenu({
            selector: '.context-menu',
            build: function ($trigger, e) {
                return {
                    callback: function (key, options) {

                    },
                    items: {

                    }
                };
            }
        });
```

Лишний код убрал.

Вот моя view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Марка", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.MarkSort })
            </th>
            <th>Модель</th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Цена", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.PriceSort })
            </th>
            <th>Количество на складе</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="context-menu">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_Car", item)
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

И вот моя partialview которая вызывается для отрисовки строк в таблице:

```
@model AutoStore.Domain.Core.Car

<tr id="@Model.Id">
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Mark.MarkName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.CarModel.ModelName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Price)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Count)</td>
</tr>
```

На partial видно что я вешаю id записи на tr(строку). Так вот. Я при вызове контекстного меню для дальнейшего редактирования хочу считать id именно той строки по которой кликнул.

Не смог найти как вытащить конкретный id конкретной строки. Но есть вариант вытащить id td'ешки по которйо кликнул, но в таком случае id'шники придётся развешивать на все тд, чего мне пока что делать не хочется, подскажите пожалуйста как можно вытащить id всей строки. PS. если что id кликнутого td вытаскивается с помощью параметра e из build. `e.target.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rowId = $(e.target).closest("tr").attr("id");
```

Comment: Igor большое спасибо, помогло.